# Intellij IDEA javadoc Documentation not found error

Tags: intellij-idea, documentation, javadoc

I have thoroughly searched all questions and precisely followed the steps mentioned here [How to view JDK external documentation in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587522/how-to-view-jdk-external-documentation-in-intellij-idea)

I have added URL also, javadoc jar file also in Platform Settings->SDK.

My Documentation path images:
[DOC PATH IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9r9i.png)
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zhVh.png)

Comment: Your Java files have a little red "J" icon. This is IntelliJ indicating that those Java files are not part of the sources. I recommend following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904052/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-intellij-red-circle-on-bottom-left-corner-of-fil) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131939/intellij-idea-files-with-a-red-circle). HOPEFULLY that should get IntelliJ to display documentation when editing those files.

Comment: Thanks A LOT!! It solved the problem! @Harmelodic

Comment: Excellent, I'll add my comment as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: I have voted but I don't have 15 reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java files have a little red "J" icon.
This is IntelliJ indicating that those Java files are not part of the sources.

I recommend following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904052/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-intellij-red-circle-on-bottom-left-corner-of-fil) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131939/intellij-idea-files-with-a-red-circle).

That should get IntelliJ to display documentation when editing those files.

Comment: I remembered to accept :)