# Getting started with IBM Cloud Object Storage Java Client - How to run sample code?

Tags: intellij-idea, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I'm trying to get started with the java-client. That's the Cos docs: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/libraries/java.html#java

Before saying what I did - I just want to be able to run the example code. I've been stuck on this simple thing for 2 days and will try any solution you will suggest.

I followed this steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-java.git
 Open IntelliJ->Import Project->select the path to ibm-cos-sdk-java->Import project from existing model (select maven)->next->next
```

Now I simply want to add the code and run it.

First try - i've tried pasting the code "CosExample.java" at the working directory created.
BUT - red circle appears, and there isn't a way to run the file. ([What does this symbol mean in IntelliJ? (red circle on bottom-left corner of file name, with 'J' in it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904052/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-intellij-red-circle-on-bottom-left-corner-of-file)) 1 
[image: 1]
Second try - i've tried opening new directory (named "S3Proj") and put the code in it at the right structure. like here. Also, to fix the red circle, I marked the java directory as "Source" so it will be able to be run. But now everything won't compile. 
[image]
What should I do ? Thanks

Edit:
After @PatrickB comment, i'm adding my first try - just using maven dependency of com.ibm.cos

Without cloning the project. It doesn't work because the line

```
import com.ibm.oauth.BasicIBMOAuthCredentials;
```

isn't compiling. (The rest does compile)
[image: 3]

The pom file for this try:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>S3Operation</groupId>
    <artifactId>S3Operation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.cos</groupId>
            <artifactId>ibm-cos-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Last edit: SOLVED
There is a bad import in the docs so it didn't compile.

Here
[https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/libraries/java.html#java?cm_sp=dw-bluemix-*-nospace-*-answers](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/libraries/java.html#java?cm_sp=dw-bluemix-_-nospace-_-answers)

This import won't compile:

import com.ibm.oauth.BasicIBMOAuthCredentials;

This is the right import:

import com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.oauth.BasicIBMOAuthCredentials;

Comment: First case - file is not located under soures root. Second case - your root module doesn't contain needed dependency (<artifactId>ibm-cos-java-sdk-core</artifactId> )

Comment: @y.bedrov please can you give me more details? The pom file DOES contains that dependency. Second - I marked the 'java' dir as source. What should I do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't clone the sdk source into your project. A more efficient way of using the cos sdk would be to create a maven project, adding the cos sdk dependency to your pom.xml e.g.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.ibm.cos</groupId>
<artifactId>ibm-cos-java-sdk</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
<type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Assuming maven is installed correctly this will automatically pull the sdk archives into your project from maven central.Then add your client code such as CosExample to src/main/java folder.

Comment: thanks, this was my first try, but the import of: 

import com.ibm.oauth.BasicIBMOAuthCredentials;

isn't compiling so I tried cloning the SDK. I'm adding in edit the screenshots relevant for it.

Comment: The import statement 'import com.ibm.oauth.BasicIBMOAuthCredentials;' doesn't look correct to me. I think it should be 'import com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.oauth.BasicIBMOAuthCredentials;'

Comment: OMG you are right
I can't believe i've been stuck on this because of error in the docs
Thanks!!!