# Intellij Ctrl+N not finding Java files

Tags: intellij-idea

Ctrl+N on IntelliJ (Ultimate 2020) is not finding Java files.

To troubleshoot this I've tried:

- Ensuring correct JDK is configured
- Ensuring no errors listed in the event log
- Ctrl+N filter has Java selected

I have two installs of IntelliJ - it works one and not the other.  I cant't figure out the difference.

What am I missing?

---

Update: I notice in the instance where this works the .java files in the source tree have a C or I icon for class/interface.  In the one which doesn't work they have a file icon with a red dot in the lower left corner.  That is odd....

Comment: Did you try to "invalidate caches and restart"

Comment: Tried it - no luck.  At restart the status bar indicated it was rebuilding the index but had the same end result.   It finds the .js files but not Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon with a `J` in an orange circle [represents](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html#common-icons) Java classes located outside of the sources root.

[image]

So basically the answer is, you need to mark the directory with your Java classes as a [Sources Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html) in order for IDEA to know that this is your production code, and these are the files eligible for compilation, as well as code completion, navigation, etc.

[image]

After that, the icons will turn blue, and the classes will become searchable:

[image]

Comment: P.S. Maven settings re specifying the directory of your sources root on reimporting a project can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-importing.html).

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  See my answer below for the steps I followed

Answer (score 0):

This question led to the solution: [What does this symbol mean in IntelliJ? (red circle on bottom-left corner of file name, with 'J' in it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904052/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-intellij-red-circle-on-bottom-left-corner-of-fil)

I clicked on the root pom.xml (Maven), right click, Maven, re-import.